# Deserializar XML para objeto vem com informações nulas

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Estou com problemas ao tentar deserializar um XML retornado pelo webservice para um objeto em meu projeto, o que acontece é que o objeto é criado, porém com todas as propriedades sem valor (nulas).

O XML que eu quero possui uma estrutura bem simples:

[image: Web service]

Ao fazer a requisição, eu obtenho esses dados e converto para XML, conforme o código abaixo:

```
public async Task<CorreioResult> CalcularFrete()
    {
        string url = $"{baseUrl}?nCdEmpresa=&sDsSenha=&sCepOrigem=09020240&sCepDestino=07070000&nVlPeso=1&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=20&nVlAltura=20&nVlLargura=20&sCdMaoPropria=N&nVlValorDeclarado=2000&sCdAvisoRecebimento=N&nCdServico=04014&nVlDiametro=20&StrRetorno=xml&nIndicaCalculo=3";
        CorreioResult result = null;
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string resultado = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = ConverterParaXml(resultado);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private CorreioResult ConverterParaXml(string data)
    {

        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CorreioResult));
            var resultado = (CorreioResult)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            return resultado;
        }

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, meu objeto CorreioResult sempre vem com os valores nulos.
Segue abaixo a classe CorreioResult:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace LojaVirtual.Models
{
[XmlRoot("Servicos")]           
[Serializable()]    
public class CorreioResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Codigo")]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "valor")]
    public int Valor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PrazoEntrega")]
    public string PrazoEntrega { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValorSemAdicionais")]
    public string ValorSemAdicionais { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Erro")]
    public string Erro { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Acredito que o código abaixo funcione para você:

```
  private CorreioResult ConverterParaXml(string data)
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CorreioResult));
            return (CorreioResult) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Abraços!

Comment: Olá, utilizando o StreamReader eu tenho uma exceção do tipo System.IO.Exception, pois ele busca um arquivo no caminho do meu parâmetro data, e este arquivo não existe.

Comment: Putz é mesmo! Pode ser a estrutura do XML... porque tem o nó cServico antes dos outros nós...

Comment: Exato, tentei refatorar minha classe CorreioResult pra ficar exatamente com a mesma estrutura do XML, mas não tive resultados, talvez por não ter experiência com xml

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

Minha consulta estava retornando um objeto dentro do , que é o cServico, então ao refletir isso na minha classe tudo funcionou como deveria.

Segue o código abaixo para quem se interessar.

```
//deve estar exatamente igual ao web service
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Servicos")]
[Serializable()]
public class CorreioResult
{
    //deve estar exatamente igual ao web service
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cServico")]
    public CorreioResultItem CorreioResultItem { get; set; } 
}

[Serializable()]
public class CorreioResultItem
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(Codigo))]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(Valor))]
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(PrazoEntrega))]
    public int PrazoEntrega { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(ValorSemAdicionais))]
    public string ValorSemAdicionais { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(Erro))]
    public int Erro { get; set; }
}
```

}